# Launching EMECA rules

Tags: moqui

The messages are being successfully polled from the server. I somehow cannot manage to have the EMECA rules process the incoming messages. Is there a special way I need to configure the EMECA rule? This is what I have:

```
<emecas xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://moqui.org/xsd/email-eca-2.0.xsd">
<emeca rule-name="processMail">
    <condition>
        <expression>true</expression>
    </condition>
    <actions>
        <service-call name="org.moqui.impl.EmailServices.save#EcaEmailMessage" in-map="context"/>
    </actions>
</emeca>
```

I can see the message being polled from the server, but no rule is fired. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer. The file with EMECA rule had a misspelled extension.